# How can I append a list item by click?

Tags: jquery, append

By click on any link on my sidebar I want to add a new list item to my breadcrump:

```
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ol> 

  $('.left-sidebar').on( 'click', 'a', function (e) {
      $(".breadcrumb").append('<li class="b_cat"><a href="#">New list item</a></li>');
  });
```

But each time I click, then it is adding more items to it. That is not what I need. So I had the idea to remove the item first and then add it. So only one list item is added:

```
 $('li').hasClass( "b_cat" ).remove();
 $(".breadcrumb").append('<li class="b_cat"><a href="#">New list item</a></li>');
```

But now there is no list item added. Actually nothing happens.

Comment: `$('li').hasClass( "b_cat" )` returns a `boolean`. Use `$('li.b_cat').remove();` instead

Comment: Usually you would see an error in the console if you are not getting expected results. Something like `.remove() is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the element with class using:

```
$('li.b_cat').remove();
```

You don't need to check if the element has a class or not because if it doesn't have that class then `.remove()` method will be never called.

Also, as you are adding a static item to the `breadcrumb`, I think you should only add once if it does not exists like:

```
if(!$(".breadcrumb > li.b_cat").length){
   $(".breadcrumb").append('<li class="b_cat"><a href="#">New list item</a></li>');
}
```

But if you adding items in the same format, but only the `breadcrumb` link text is changing, then you can only update that part, instead of adding the item multiple times like:

```
$('.left-sidebar').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  if (!$(".breadcrumb > li.b_cat").length) {
    $(".breadcrumb").append('<li class="b_cat"><a href="#"></a></li>');
  }

  // Get clicked link text
  var currentLink = $(this).text();
  $(".breadcrumb > li.b_cat > a").text(currentLink)
});
```

Comment: You got me... :)